# How do I get the indexOf an element using a criteria function

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get the `indexOf` an object in an array, by using a criteria function.

**attempt1:** works, but is inefficient, as I have to iterate the array twice.

**attempt2:** doesn't work (obviously), but indicates what I'd like to achieve.

```js
const dataSet = [{ name: "obj1" }, { name: "obj2" }, { name: "obj3" }, { name: "obj4" }, { name: "obj5" }]

const attempt1 = dataSet.indexOf(dataSet.find(d => d.name === 'obj3'))

const attempt2 = dataSet.indexOf(d => d.name === 'obj3')

console.log(attempt1)
console.log(attempt2)
```

Comment: You are looking for `findIndex` which takes a predicate. Note that this is not supported by IE 11 (which `find` from your attempt 1 isn't either).

Comment: Instead of using `find` method, use `findIndex` method: https://developer.mozilla.org//Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: In attempt2, it is searching for the actual function `d => d.name === 'obj3'` in `dataSet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const dataSet = [{ name: "obj1" }, { name: "obj2" }, { name: "obj3" }, { name: "obj4" }, { name: "obj5" }]

const attempt2 = dataSet.findIndex(d => d.name === 'obj3')

console.log(attempt2)
```

> Why second one is not working whereas first attempt is working  ?

`indexOf` expects a searchElement value to be searched so in the first attempt you used `find` inside `indexOf` which returns a value whereas in second attempt you passed a function which not what `indexOf` expects